# Женский род слова - факелоносец.

Tags: грамотная-речь

Извините за беспокойство, но я не нашёл в сети ответа. Объясните мне, человеку со средним образованием, почему так: он - переносчик,она - переносчица, а он факелоносец и она факелоносец? У слова факелоносец нет женского рода?. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

"-Носчик" и "-носец" - это разные основы, и они подчиняются разным законам. Так что с этой стороны все объяснимо. А вот "почему" так - это уже отдельный разговор. Самый верный ответ на такие вопросы - так уж сложилось. Язык не подчиняется каким-то наперед заданным требованиям и аналогиям. Так что давайте разбираться отдельно с переносчиком и факелоносцем.
С первым все понятно. У слов, обозначающих профессию, и близких к ним по значению на "-чик" (часто и на -ик) есть вполне продуктивная и семантически оправданная модель для образования женского рода "-чица".  Летчик - летчица, наводчик - наводчица, отказчик - отказчица.
Со вторым - сложнее. Какую модель для слов подобным значением на "-ец" можно было бы предложить?
~1. -ец - -иха: используется в основном для обозначения жен или самок животных: купчиха, зайчиха и проч. реже для качеств: глупец-глупчиха.
~2. -ец - (-ка, -янка/анка/енка, йика) - и, возможно, подобные 
используются в основном для национальностей и жителей разных стран, реже городов (этохоронимов): норвежка, китаянка, тобольчанка, петербурженка  и т.п.;
реже в других случаях, но тоже не "профессиональных": самец-самка.
~3. -ец -  -ица: в числе прочего для женских профессий: жнец-жница, мироносец-мироносица.
~4. Единичные непродкутивные варианты типа лжец-лгунья, швец-швея, вдовец-вдова, чтец-чтица и проч.

Понятно, что первые два варианта для нас не подходят, возможен только третий вариант. Т.е. ***факелоносец-факелоносица***. И такой вариант действительно иногда встречается в текстах. Но в силу крайней неуклюжести и малой употребительности он не стал нормативным и не вошел в словари.

Вообще образование женских форм - это отдельная область, весьма запутанная и слабо формализуемая. Даже разобранный случай на мужской формы на -ец вполне демонстрирует обилие вариантов. А я даже не уверен, что вспомнил все. Потому что в древности были и другие, возможно какие-то и сохранились - и пошли мимо меня.

Comment: Да факел несут обычно мужчины, вот язык и "сопротивляется". Но верно, возможно только "факелоносица"

Comment: На Олимпиадах-то как раз женщины-факелоносцы возможны. В Греции они и огонь зажигают. Вот в вне Олимпиад - это да. Тяжелые факелы не для женских рук. 

>Но верно, возможно только "факелоносица".  
  
Да это-то понятно. Жен-мироносиц никто не отменял, а других продуктивных для данной семантики просто нет.  
Меня больше забавляет вопрос, откуда такое многообразие парадигм жля женских форм при разных значениях и есть ли хоть какая-то надежда на систематизацию хотя бы наиболее продуктивных: как когда и почему ипотребляется именно такая форма.